# C# webservices. Convertable to "string" is required

Tags: c#, web-services

I am creating a mediator for my .svc webservice and I am stuck with return. It's been giving me an error

> an object of type is convertable to "string" is required

I dont know what do I have to return. Well here is my code.

```
var proxy = SomeProxy();
try
{
    var contact = proxy.FindContactByLogin("0002221111", "test123", false);
    if (contact.Result != SomeService.Results.Succeeded)
    {
        Assert.Fail(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, contact.Errors.ToString()));
        return;
    }

    var result = proxy.GetAccountsListByContactID(contact.Value.ID);
    if (result.Result == SomeService.Results.Succeeded)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string error in result.Errors)
            return error;

            //Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
finally
{
    proxy.Close();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: that is the whole error message that i am getting. no revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to debug to determine exactly where the code is failing.

1. Your try block has no catch.  That's where your handling should go.
2. The error suggests that you are attempting a string conversion.  It might be the `contact.Errors.Tostring()` call on line 6

Comment: Yes. ive change the ToString to ToArray(), and return "";, and it worked like charm. Thanks for the help.